# Every time the same error when installing

Tags: apt, software-installation, latex, lyx

Whenever I install something (must happened when I re-installed Lyx somehow..) I receive following output, e.g. for qpdfview:

```
user@system:~$ sudo apt-get install qpdfview
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpoppler-qt5-1 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite qpdfview-djvu-plugin qpdfview-ps-plugin
  qpdfview-translations
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpoppler-qt5-1 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite qpdfview qpdfview-djvu-plugin
  qpdfview-ps-plugin qpdfview-translations
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1.018 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5.043 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 libpoppler-qt5-1 amd64 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.10 [140 kB]
Get:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libqt5printsupport5 amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.3 [178 kB]
Get:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libqt5sql5 amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.3 [115 kB]
Get:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libqt5sql5-sqlite amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.3 [40,2 kB]
Get:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 qpdfview amd64 0.4.14-1build1 [330 kB]
Get:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 qpdfview-djvu-plugin amd64 0.4.14-1build1 [22,9 kB]
Get:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 qpdfview-ps-plugin amd64 0.4.14-1build1 [17,2 kB]
Get:8 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 qpdfview-translations all 0.4.14-1build1 [175 kB]
Fetched 1.018 kB in 0s (2.828 kB/s)            
Selecting previously unselected package libpoppler-qt5-1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 233831 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libpoppler-qt5-1_0.62.0-2ubuntu2.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpoppler-qt5-1:amd64 (0.62.0-2ubuntu2.10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqt5printsupport5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../1-libqt5printsupport5_5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt5printsupport5:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqt5sql5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../2-libqt5sql5_5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt5sql5:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../3-libqt5sql5-sqlite_5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package qpdfview.
Preparing to unpack .../4-qpdfview_0.4.14-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qpdfview (0.4.14-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package qpdfview-djvu-plugin.
Preparing to unpack .../5-qpdfview-djvu-plugin_0.4.14-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qpdfview-djvu-plugin (0.4.14-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package qpdfview-ps-plugin.
Preparing to unpack .../6-qpdfview-ps-plugin_0.4.14-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qpdfview-ps-plugin (0.4.14-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package qpdfview-translations.
Preparing to unpack .../7-qpdfview-translations_0.4.14-1build1_all.deb ...
Unpacking qpdfview-translations (0.4.14-1build1) ...
Setting up tex-common (6.09) ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... done.
Running mktexlsr /var/lib/texmf ... done.
Building format(s) --all.
    This may take some time... 
fmtutil failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/fmtutil.FJZr9PUM
Please include this file if you report a bug.

dpkg: error processing package tex-common (--configure):
 installed tex-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-extra:
 texlive-latex-extra depends on tex-common (>= 6); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-science:
 texlive-science depends on tex-common (>= 6); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-science (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libpoppler-qt5-1:amd64 (0.62.0-2ubuntu2.10) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                      dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-pictures:
 texlive-pictures depends on tex-common (>= 6); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-pictures (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tex-gyre:
 tex-gyre depends on tex-common (>= 6); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package tex-gyre (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tipa:
 tipa depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package tipa (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of preview-latex-style:
 preview-latex-style depends on tex-common (>= 6); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package preview-latex-style (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up libqt5printsupport5:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.3) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lyx-common:
 lyx-common depends on tex-common (>= 6); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lyx-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libqt5sql5:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.3) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-recommended:
 texlive-fonts-recommended depends on tex-common (>= 6); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lyx:
 lyx depends on lyx-common (= 2.3.3-1~bionic~ppa1); however:
  Package lyx-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lyx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-base:
 texlive-latex-base depends on tex-common (>= 6); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-recommended:
 texlive-latex-recommended depends on tex-common (>= 6); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-latex-recommended depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2017.20170628); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-greek:
 texlive-lang-greek depends on tex-common (>= 6); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-greek (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up qpdfview (0.4.14-1build1) ...
Setting up qpdfview-translations (0.4.14-1build1) ...
Setting up qpdfview-ps-plugin (0.4.14-1build1) ...
Setting up qpdfview-djvu-plugin (0.4.14-1build1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
 texlive-latex-extra
 texlive-science
 texlive-pictures
 tex-gyre
 tipa
 preview-latex-style
 lyx-common
 texlive-fonts-recommended
 lyx
 texlive-latex-base
 texlive-latex-recommended
 texlive-lang-greek
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I can see that it is indeed somehow related to TeX - on the other side it works (finally..) :D

**edit**: The demanded outputs are:

```
user@system:~$ which fmtutil
/usr/bin/fmtutil

user@system:~$ apt-cache policy $(dpkg -S $(which fmtutil) | awk '{print $1}')
texlive-base:
  Installed: 2017.20180305-1
  Candidate: 2017.20180305-1
  Version table:
 *** 2017.20180305-1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: "fmtutil failed. Output has been stored in /tmp/fmtutil.FJZr9PUM
Please include this file if you report a bug."  Please edit your question to include that output.

Comment: Please add output of `which fmtutil` and `apt-cache policy $(dpkg -S $(which fmtutil) | awk '{print $1}')` to the question.

Comment: Thanks already! I added the outputs.

Comment: Ah, I missed the file. Actually, there is only fmtutil.1qSDMGSH and fmtutil.WskCj8gX. But I cannot open or copy them..?